# bash profile file contents in MacBook Air laptop

Tags: python

I am installing open cv python on MacBook Air laptop, while loading I got an error which says bash_profile file does not available.when I looked at open cv python procedure, it says that if bash file does not available create it or open the available file and append the /user/local/
then I opened the terminal on my MacBook Air laptop, and using the vi command opened the ~/.bash_profile , it contains some statements. my question is shall I append the /user/local statement on the available statements or delete all the statements before appending the /user/local/path

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think what you need is to add the location of an executable to your `$PATH` environmental variable. The `$PATH` variable contains directories, which you can refer to without the explicit need to point the full path.

Example - if you want to run `/home/user/program/myprogram` from every location you go to, you have to include `/home/user/program` to your $PATH variable.

Make a backup copy of your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
cp ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_profile.backup
```

Open it with a text editor (I see you prefer `vi`) and add the following at the bottom:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Save the file and do:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

to make the change active for your current shell.

This will allow you to execute all executable files in that directory from every location, including python (if it is located there).